# JSF dataTable: conditional filter facets

Tags: jsf, input, primefaces, filter, facet

I've got a dynamic dataTable and would like to display different filter types depending on the column but it seems that I can only use one object within a filter facet at a time. If I try to use multiple input types  I get a

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be cast to javax.faces.component.ValueHolder
```

My current (not working) code looks like this:

```
<f:facet name="filter">
  <p:inputText onkeyup="PF('myTable').filter()" rendered="#{column.filterType=='TEXT'}" />
  <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('myTable').filter()" rendered="#{column.filterType=='LIST'}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{column.filterMap}" />
  </p:selectOneMenu>
 </f:facet>
```

The inputText and selectOneMenus are displayed correctly, but I can't filter my table because of the ClassCast Exception.
If I only use one of the input types, the filtering works as expected.

Is it possible to conditionally show different filter facets or input types within the facet?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: Any solution so far? The same problem I have also!

Answer (score 0):

The only "solution" I found, is to always use selectOneMenus and make them editable and look like inputTexts if the filter type is "TEXT"

```
 <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('myTable').filter()" editable="#{column.filterType=='TEXT'}" styleClass="#{column.filterType}">
```

Comment: Tried wrapping both inputs in a span/div?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback with your workaround! ...unfortunately it doesn't work for me as I need a <p:selectCheckboxMenu> control, so several values has to be selected.
@Kukeltje I have tried wrapping both controls with div/span (wraping both and by each one) - didn't help. Would you have any other thoughts - you are most welcome to share them!

Answer (score -1):

following your 2nd comment I tested this code and it works; The idea is that the filter depends on the column, so:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{column.attribute}" filterMatchMode="contains" rendered="#{column.filterType=='TEXT'}" >
    <f:facet name="filter">
      <p:inputText onkeyup="PF('myTable').filter()" />
     </f:facet>
</p:column>

<p:column filterBy="#{column.attribute}" filterMatchMode="equals" rendered="#{column.filterType=='LIST'}">    
    <f:facet name="filter">
      <p:selectOneMenu onchange="PF('myTable').filter()" >
        <f:selectItems value="#{column.filterMap}" />
      </p:selectOneMenu>
    </f:facet>
</p:column>
```

you show and hide the column, not the filter.

**NB : The filter mode of an inputText is contains AND for a List is Equals.**

Comment: the name needs to be "filter". It's a predefined name for the filter facet. If you change the name, the input type is not visible in the table header anymore...

Comment: We're working with the <p:toolbar />  and it's visible.

Comment: It has to be a filter for each column in the header of my dynamically created dataTable... something like this: primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/filter.xhtml

Comment: I appreciate your effort but it seems you don't understand what I'm trying to do. Since it is a **dynamically** created table there are no <p:column> tags but only one <p:columns> if I would manually create the table and each column I wouldn't have the problems I have...

Comment: I didn't test it yet, but you can try the JSTL if-else options.